# AJAX Request and on page javascript not registering?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On an order confirmation page I am making an AJAX request to a page that has a javascript code that tracks cookies and records data. When I fire the request to the other page with the javascript code nothing seems to be happening.

Is this because javascript is executed on the client side and the AJAX request is only getting the server side response?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Whenever you post your question always provide great degree of explanation and code which you written, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is correct, in order to fire the javascript code on another page you have to load the page.

There are a couple of (dirty) tricks to do this and I would recommend not using any of them.

---

Your best call is to load the cookie from the order confirmation page (which is origin based, so can be used on other pages on the same domain)